# Are questions about finding specific books on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I am highly unfamiliar with this portion of Writers, so forgive me if this is off-topic.

While browsing Writers SE, I came across someone who mentioned that Science Fiction & Fantasy SE gets specific book requests all the time (that is, someone is looking for a book they once read, and can now no longer remember its title).

What if the book is not Science Fiction or Fantasy? Where would I ask a question about, say, an Historical Fiction book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's now a Literature Stack Exchange site where you can ask this kind of question (or, for that matter, other general questions about literature, books, publication process, and a wide variety of other questions about written works - even, for example, song lyrics).

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, there is currently no place on the Stack Exchange network where you can get a non-scifi/fantasy book identified. There was a literature site but it [never made it out of beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature).

Literature questions are off-topic here on Writers, [as per community decision](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242/are-literature-questions-appropriate-on-writers-se).

Comment: Well drat. Might you know of a place where I *could* make such a request?

Comment: Perhaps http://whatwasthatbook.livejournal.com/profile, or http://www.whatsthatbook.com/ could help?

Comment: Eh... possibly. Thanks for the links, I'll check them out.